# Various integration theories

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Could anyone briefly explain, or point me towards a resource explaining, the main differences between the main integration theories, namely:

- Riemann Integration
- Riemann-Stieltjes Integration
- Lebesgue Integration
- Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integration

I understand that this a question with a potentially very long answer, since integration is no small theory. I can find information on these integrals separately, but I would really be interested in a comparison of these integrals with one another.

Comment: Perhaps, you might be interested in [this paper](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Bartle625-632.pdf)